# How to display data in two columns in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. How can I display products in two columns?

When I write the following, the right column will display the same products, but I want to display
some in the left and  some in the right columns.

```
#main_container  
.left_col

%div{"data-hook" => "___homepage_featured_products"}

%h3

   Featured Activities
 - @featured.each do |pr|
   - @product = pr
   %a.box{:href=>url_for(@product), :title=>"#{@product.name} | #{@product.location}"}
     - if @product.images[0]
       .img{:style=>"background-image: url('#{@product.images[0].attachment.url(:original)}')"}
       .details
         %h3
           = @product.name.truncate 20
         %p.infos
           = image_tag @product.activity_type.icon, :class=>"pictogram" rescue ''
           %span= @product.activity_type.name.titleize rescue ''
           \/
           %span.price= number_to_currency @product.price rescue ''
           \/
           = @product.location
           \/
           = @product.level
         %p
           = @product.description.truncate(120) rescue ''

.right_col
```

Comment: Please read [the formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You need to indent your code by 4 spaces, or select it and press `Ctrl-K`.

Answer (score 1):

You could put each product into its own div, and then use CSS to float them to the left so that a maximum of 2 boxes will appear next to each other horizontally. This will give the effect of a 2 column layout. As an example:

```
#main_container { width: 900px; }
.featured_product { width: 450px; float: left; }
```

Add padding etc as needed.

Alternatively you could split the array after you retrieve it from the database and run the code twice, once in the left column and once in the right:

```
@left, @right = @featured.in_groups_of((@featured.count / 2.0).ceil, false)
```